# MS-ACCESS How to modify all forms' KeyDown events with a module - alternative disabling F11 key hide/unhide navigation pane

Tags: forms, ms-access, module, keydown

I have a DB with some forms.

The DB starts with a login form that sets a `TempVars!CurrentSecurity.Value` based on the user logged in (as `Admin` or common `User`).

All the other forms have a `Form_KeyDown` event that will call a module where there is a function/sub that has to change the behavior of F11 (hide/show the navigation pane) depending from the current `TempVars!CurrentSecurity.Value` (Admin/User).

For instance: if the current logged account is an Admin, the F11 key is enabled, else not..

So i tried in this way:

in the Form_KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
CheckF11 (KeyCode)
end sub
```

in the module:

```
Public Function CheckF11(KeyCode As Integer)
If TempVars!CurrentSecurity.Value <> "Admin" Then
 If KeyCode = 122 Then KeyCode = 0
End If
End Function
```

The form's KeyPreview property is already set to True but this doesn't work anyway.. help

Comment: Admin is db developer? Only developer should even see Navigation Pane. And developer should know about shift key bypass on open. I disable all AccessSpecialKeys, Navigation Pane, right click menus, and set customized ribbon in db Options. I use shift key bypass when opening db. Admin user is not developer even tho they do have some additional privileges other users don't, they still don't have developer accessibility. I know, a user might learn about shift-key bypass and if that is a concern, probably need to use a different db platform like SQLServerExpress.

Comment: Admin is a String value from a table field called Accounts where the login form checks if the the current logged user matches the username and password values then checks the relative Security Level (Admin / User) and gives to the TempVars!CurrentSecurity.Value the relative String

Comment: I didn't know about shift key bypass on open, but as you said, this could be learned by a normal user so i think controlling behaviors as i described is much better

Comment: Don't need F11 to open/close Navigation Pane. If the pane bar is visible, just click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function must send result back to calling procedure.
Public function doesn't really reduce code.

This works:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
KeyCode = CheckF11(KeyCode)
End Sub
```

```
Public Function CheckF11(intKey As Integer)
If TempVars!CurrentSecurity.Value <> "Admin" Then
 If intKey = 122 Then CheckF11 = 0
End If
End Function
```

Comment: your code works fine till at i return to Admin value where it seems to be stocked to `CheckF11 = 0` so i added `Else CheckF11 = 122`
thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Why would the logged-in user change?

Comment: cause i want to log from a different workstation as Admin to make small changes maybe or different users can log on the same workstation.

Comment: But isn't each user opening their own copy of frontend for a split db?

Comment: all actions on this Db are tracked into a log table with the current user account credentials, reports and records modified by a user will be tracked. So for instance if the workstation's operator (user) will change, he/she can log with his account in order to be tracked correctly!

Comment: A multi-user database should be split and each user run their own copy of frontend. You, the developer, would make design changes to a master original and distribute the revised frontend to users. Design changes to backend would be done when users are not interacting with db. Users should not modify design.

Comment: quote: But isn't each user opening their own copy of frontend for a split db?
Yes the will but many user can use the same Db on the same workstation

Comment: Fine, as long as they aren't opening and running the same copy on same machine. So someone logs in and goes to lunch leaving file open and another user opens the same file on that machine. Not good. No matter what machine they sit at, should open their own copy from their user folder.